# How do I use getterSetter in an angular directive with an isolated scope?

Tags: angularjs, getter-setter, directive

I'm having trouble getting a getterSetter to work in a ng-model directive.
Please, look at this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Tx0nyvvbuKqf1ZpsRTPu?p=preview

If you use the uncommented template, the example behaves as if it didn't understand that getSet() is a function it should call.

If you uncomment the other template (and comment out the first one), the input is connected to the {{ }} as expected.

Why is the getterSetter not working?

Thank you for help!

This is the code:

javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])

.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.something = "hahaha";
}])

/*
 * attributes:
 *   - value - a variable to store the input value in
 *
 */
.directive('inputNumber', ['$log', function( $log ) {

  var linker = function( scope, element, attrs) {
    $log.info('inputNumber linker called! value = "' + scope.value + '".');

    scope.getSet = function( newValue ) {
      if( angular.isDefined( newValue ) ) {
        scope.value = newValue;
      }
      return scope.value;
    }

  }
  return {
           restrict : 'E',
//           template: '<p>Say something! {{ value }}</p><input ng-model="value" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: false }"></input>',
           template: '<p>Say something! {{ getSet() }}</p><input ng-model="getSet" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"></input>',
           link: linker,
           scope: {
            value: '='
           }
         };
}])
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input-number value="something" ></input-number>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is `ngModelOptions` is only available in angular 1.3, but you're using angular 1.2.x. Try to modify your script tag to use `1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your directive's template should be set to the model (in this case 'value').

```
 template: '<p>Say something! {{ getSet() }}</p><input ng-model="value" 
      ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"></input>'
```

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4q7yfEeOrI2cKJxqV52v?p=preview)

Comment: This is cheating because this way, the getSet function is only used to get the value and not to set it, which means it can't check it, change it, or cause side effects. Actually, if you do this, the ng-model-options="..." isn't necessary at all.